# Export Multiple tables from SQL Server to several CSV files

Tags: sql-server

I need to export multiple tables from SQL Server to several flat files. Is there any easy way to do this apart from using SSIS import and Export Wizard?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's easier, but you can select all the records in SSMS, right click and save the results as a CSV.

Answer (score 0):

The other thing that you can do is to run a `SELECT * FROM` query, and then save those results to file. There is an option for this is Management Studio.